# Firebase authentication REST API setAccountInfo endpoint ignores returnSecureToken

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update the `displayName` property of a user using the `setAccountInfo` endpoint as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-update-profile).

The display name is updated but the `returnSecureToken` property is ignored. In the JSON reply `idToken` and `refreshToken` are never there, and there is an extra `emailVerified` not mentioned in the documentation.

Is this bad / outdated documentation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

`returnSecureToken` is only needed in operations where the old ID token is revoked. If you are updating the displayName, the existing ID token/refresh token remains valid. If you are updating the password or the email, the tokens are revoked and you need new ones. The Auth backend will return new tokens as after an email/password update, all existing sessions are revoked for security reason.

To get back the user data, use the `getAccountInfo` endpoint. That is the best way to populate a user. I believe `setAccountInfo` may return different data depending on what it is used for.

Comment: I know that the `idToken` is not required here. The point is that the documentation seems to be wrong.

Comment: returnSecureToken will only return a new token when necessary. The documentation should be updated to mention that. The Firebase Auth backend will not return a new refresh token every time an update profile is initiated. If you want a new refresh token you can force a refresh and exchange the existing refresh token for a new one using https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token You can file a bug with Firebase support to clarify this in the official reference.

Comment: Thank you. I Kept going through my code for an hour trying to figure out what was wrong and then got into this question and figured that its just their wrong documentation.

Comment: But it is necessary in this case, since displayName is contained within the token...